# A conjecture about odd path and odd cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Let $k$ be a positive integer and $G=(V,E)$ be a $2$-connected simple graph.Suppose $v\in V(G)$ satisfy:

$(1)$there exists at least one vertex $u\in V(G)\backslash\{v\}$ such that $u$ is not adjacent with $v$;

$(2)$for any $u\in V(G)\backslash\{v\}$ such that $u$ is not adjacent with $v$,there is a $u$-$v$ path in $G$ which has an odd length $\geq2k+1$.

I want to ask is it ture that there must exists a odd cycle in $G$ whose length$\geq2k+1$.

Comment: What about a complete bipartite graph?

Comment: Sorry,I forgot "odd"!

Comment: An odd path means a path of odd length?

Comment: Yes,it is my meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

False. As we want a counterexample, we naturally start with the Petersen graph, P. Note that for any vertex v of P and non-adjacent edge uw of P there is a Hamiltonian path from v to w that does not use the uw edge. On the other hand, there is no Hamiltonian cycle in P.

Our graph G will have 10t+15 vertices (where t is some large number) and is obtained from P by subdividing each edge with a vertex and replacing each original vertex by t vertices, connected to each other and to the subdividing vertices which the original vertex was connected to. Let v be a vertex that was not obtained by subdividing an edge and let 2k+1=9t+16 (or +17, whichever is odd). Using the above mentioned properties of P, it is easy to see that G satisfies the requirements if t is big enough.

This graph is even 3-connected and can be generalized to give even stronger counterexamples.

Note that my original construction used t=2, which is not sufficient for the above reasoning, as was noted in the comment by Dani.

Comment: I fount a 29 long cycle in your graph. Since it is too big to draw it, i will describe how to find it. There is a 9 long cycle in the Petersen graph which naturally yields a 27 long cycle in your graph. Now we can use that by subdividing edges and replacing vertices you created a lot of triangles. And by the help of two such triangles we can expand it to a cycle of length 29.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I've missed that! Nevertheless, I think the main idea is correct, so let me fix my construction accordingly.

Comment: I actually really like the idea of your construction! But i just happen to have another question. Now you have t-clicques instead of original vertices. And in one such t-clicque, there is the vertex $v$. But there are vertices in the closest t-clicques which are not adjacent to $v$. How do you ensure that there is a path of length greater than $9t+15$ from $v$ to them? This length essentially means that we have to at least touch every t-clicque, and in your construction we can use every edge only once, so without a Hamiltonian cycle i'm not sure that we can achieve this.

Comment: If u and v are adjacent vertices of the Petersen-graph, then there is a walk that starts at u, ends at v and uses every vertex once, except for u, which is used twice. In G, this can be realized by a path, as we can take different vertices from the blown-up of u. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does! Actualy this means that the property that 'there is a Hamiltonian path between $v$ and any vertex not adjacent to $v$' is preserved when $t$ is large enough (greater than 3 is sufficient). This might help others who would like to verify your counterexample!

Comment: na azert!... ;)

Comment: domotorp,Thank you very much for your help!Would you like to give a revised counterexample?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - I have revised it already after Dani's first comment, the current one is good.

Comment: I can also comfirm this. The counterexample is valid. There is no need to revise it.